# Spring 14 Delegated Authentication SSO stopped working

Tags: delegated-authentication

Is anyone else using Delegated Authentication to Single Sign-On to Salesforce?  It was working fine for a year but stopped this weekend after our org was updated to Spring '14.  After login we are redirected to this page: 
https://na9.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/ic/ICNotNeeded
with a message stating
Activation complete  Your device has been automatically activated based upon network location.

We click Continue and are redirected to the Login page instead of being redirected to the home page!

Anyone else experience this?